# Why can't VS2017 coroutines return void?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, coroutine

I was doing some experiments with the proposed c++ co-routines that are currently experimental in VS2017. I simply wanted to have a co-routine that doesn't return anything but calls co_await on some co-routine object that, let's say, does some processing on another thread before resuming. However, VS will not compile even the most rudimentary co-routine program that returns void. For instance:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <experimental\coroutine>

using namespace std::experimental;

void bob()
{
    co_await suspend_always{};
}

int main()
{
    bob();
}
```

results in the errors:

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\experimental\resumable(46):
>   error C2825: '_Ret': must be a class or namespace when followed by
>   '::' 1>d:\dev\coroutinestest\main.cpp(10): note: see reference to
>   class template instantiation
>   'std::experimental::coroutine_traits' being compiled
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\experimental\resumable(46):
>   error C2510: '_Ret': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\experimental\resumable(46):
>   error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'promise_type' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\experimental\resumable(46):
>   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Now I assume that this error is due to void::promise_type being nonsensical, however why is the promise type even being instantiated when there's nothing to return? I would expect to be able to return nothing from a co-routine. Is this just a current bug in the implementation or am I misunderstanding the use of co-routines.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All talks/documentation I have perused show coroutines returning any non-void type you wish (Assuming it meets some base criteria). However they don't explicitly say why void is not valid for coroutines. I can full imagine a coroutine that handles jobs (using co_await to put a job on a worker's queue) and when it returns, not wanting to return a value. 

As you suggest though I might have resort to a future<void> or some other dummy type as a workaround but this does seem like that, a workaround at best, a bug at worst.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the issue. I watched and read a number of presentations/posts on MS' proposal and I didn't get the impression that there had to be a non-void return type. Since posting I went and found the Wording on Coroutines by Gor and yes it does specify a return type is required. I've also since read other posts on the matter by Chris Kohloff and others with concerns on the proposal and it seems that MS' implementation may be rather flawed at present and needs work. Therefore I think I'll refrain from using it in any production code.

Answer (score 5):

Of course it CAN return `void`. The reason it doesn't is - no one implements the coroutine protocol for `void`. You can implement it on your own. The coroutine protocol for a return type is satisfied by providing a specialization for `coroutine_traits`.

To make `void` a valid return type for coroutines, you can do this:

```
namespace std::experimental
{
    template<class... T>
    struct coroutine_traits<void, T...>
    {
        struct promise_type
        {
            void get_return_object() {}

            void set_exception(exception_ptr const&) noexcept {}

            bool initial_suspend() noexcept
            {
                return false;
            }

            bool final_suspend() noexcept
            {
                return false;
            }

            void return_void() noexcept {}
        };
    };
}
```

This allows your example to compile.

However, note that in your example, calling `co_await suspend_always{};` will cause memory leak, this is because `coroutine_handle` is much like a raw-pointer, and you're on your own to ensure the coroutine gets destroyed.

As a side note, the coroutine emulation library [CO2](https://github.com/jamboree/co2), however, takes another decision - its `co2::coroutine` has unique-ownership, so a call to `CO2_AWAIT(suspend_always{});` won't leak memory, it just cancels the coroutine.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled across this question when trying to debug compiler error messages. The solution for me was to make the function return an `IAsyncAction` instead of returning `void`.